# Excelsheet query

Tags: excel, string

How can I find the last word from any particular cell in excel sheet if cell contains multiple words or instructions?

For ex- The below string is in particular cell:

> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Sample Pictures\Blue hills.jpg

My requirement is to search only last word in that cell i.e. Blue hills.jpg.

Comment: which programming language? if at all...

Comment: Do you wish to search the sheet but only include the last word of a column in the search?

Answer (score 2):

If "\" is you delimiter then this formula will do the trick. Just replace E5 with your cell.

```
=CLEAN(TRIM(RIGHT(E5;LEN(E5)-FIND("*";SUBSTITUTE(E5;"\";"*";LEN(E5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E5;"\";"")))))))
```